# Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin

Tags: angular, spring-boot, microservices, api-gateway

I have developed my backend solution with spring boot (microservice) and the frontend with angular. When I request through postman it's ok. But from the frontend side, it's not loaded, and there shows an error (i.e. Access Control Origin header not present). When I added 'CorsWebFilter' this error is different (Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin). I searched a lot but doesn't find any solution. Please, help me.

[NOTE: Other services don't contain any origin header]

Spring Boot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My API Gateway Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ApiGatewayConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter filter;

    @Value("${service.security.secure-key-username}")
    private String SECURITY_KEY_USERNAME;

    @Value("${service.security.secure-key-password}")
    private String SECURITY_KEY_PASSWORD;

    private static String authorizationKey = "Authorization";

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        String authorizationValue = getAuthorization();
        return builder.routes()
                .route("auth-service", r -> r.path("/auth-service/**").filters(f -> f.filter(filter)).uri("lb://auth-service"))
                .route("currency-exchange", r -> r.path("/currency-exchange/**").filters(f -> f.filter(filter).addRequestHeader(authorizationKey, authorizationValue)).uri("lb://currency-exchange"))
                .route("currency-conversion", r -> r.path("/currency-conversion/**").filters(f -> f.filter(filter).addRequestHeader(authorizationKey, authorizationValue)).uri("lb://currency-conversion"))
                .route("hindu-religious", r -> r.path("/hindu-religious/image/**").filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader(authorizationKey, authorizationValue)).uri("lb://hindu-religious"))
                .route("hindu-religious", r -> r.path("/hindu-religious/**").filters(f -> f.filter(filter).addRequestHeader(authorizationKey, authorizationValue)).uri("lb://hindu-religious"))
                .build();
    }

    private String getAuthorization() {
        String auth = SECURITY_KEY_USERNAME + ":" + SECURITY_KEY_PASSWORD;
        String base64Text = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());
        String authKey = "Basic " + base64Text;
        return authKey;
    }
}
```

CROS Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        final CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);
        corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("*")` is generally bad practice, while you call it twice.

Comment: I've given my host origin but there show the same multiple origin header (host_ip, *) issue.

Comment: Anyway, I've bypassed it using filterer. I'm not sure if this is a temporary or permanent solution.